# calling a view in django again and again

Tags: django, django-templates

Suppose I have a list of buttons in my django template and I want to change a variable in my database on clicking that button. Here is the code of that template.

```
{% for i in data %}  
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.rollno }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
        <td> 
            <a class='btn btn-danger' href='add/{{i.id}}/{{stri}}'> {{stri}} </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Jquery code of this template:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-success');
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-danger');
    });
});
```

The button in above code is a toggle(on/off) button. Therefore, in jquery I wrote  a code to switch it on/off.
By default all the buttons are in off state.

I have called a view every time a button is clicked and then returned this url. But this switches every button in default state ie off state. And because every time the same page is loaded, I am unable to get to the previous page on clicking back button but getting the same page the no of times I called the view.

Every button belongs to an IntegerField() in database.

I am new to Django. Please suggest me a better way to do this. Maybe I could save the changes in an array and then pass it to view at the time of submitting or something similar to this and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First off you might want to use a form instead. Since you are going to store the data 
    in your dbms, use "POST". Your above code, activates every button because you did not specify which button you wanted to press. So to prevent that from happening, you can either do it as shown below, to create an onclick event which only sents the id and string to the respective url, or do it the django way
 "{% url 'urlname' id=id, stri=stri %}", whichever you prefer.

```
<form id="activate" method="POST"> 
{% for i in data %}  
 <tr>
    <td>{{ i.rollno }}</td>
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
    <td> 
        <a class='btn btn-danger' id="activateButton" onclick="activate({{i.id}}, {{stri}})"> {{stri}} </a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</form>

function activate(id, string){
    if($('#activateButton').hasClass('btn-success');
    $('#activateButton').toggleClass('btn-danger');
    }else{
        $('#activateButton').toggleClass('btn-success');
    }
    var url = 'add/{{i.id}}/{{str}}'
    $('#change').attr('action', url)
    $('#change').submit()
});
```

You can access the id and string parameter in your view depending on how you write it.
for this case, I am assuming you are using url params. So your view should look something like that

```
def activate(request, id, strin):
    # view code
    #store id and string into dbms
```

I hope this helps clarify some doubts on the usage of django, and I hope I have understood your question correctly.